Conditional formatting row-by-row for entire column
In LibreOffice Calc, how do I conditionally format the entire column A so that each individual cell in that column is highlighted green if it is greater than its corresponding cell in column B?
If I use the formula =$A1>$B1 in the conditional formatting dialogue with the condition "formula is," that just compares cells A1 and B1 and highlights the entire row in green if the condition for just those two cells is met. Instead, I want the comparison to be applied individually for each pair of cells.
For example:


If A3 is greater than B3, should A3 be highlighted or the entire column A?

@ReddyLutonadio Just A3 should be highlighted. Thanks. (:

You need to select the entire column (if I understood your request correctly).

Select column A
Go to Format -> Conditional -> Condition -> More Rules
Under Condition 1 box, select Formula is, then enter your formula. Select the sytle, press OK.


Demo

